# Pagination links are not showing in codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I use  codeigniter pagination class to paginate my records, below you can see my code

```
$data['success'] = "";
  $data['error'] = "";
  $data['offset'] = 0;

  $this->load->library('pagination');
  $per_page = 4;
  $total = $this->m_workshop->totalworkshoppay();
  $baseUrl = site_url('sitemanager/workshop/workshopayment');
  $data['query'] = $this->m_workshop->getallwpay($per_page, (int) $this->uri->segment(4));     
  $confignew['base_url'] = $baseUrl;
  $confignew['total_rows'] = $total;
  $confignew['per_page'] = $per_page;
  $confignew['uri_segment'] = '4';
  $this->pagination->initialize($confignew);


  $data['offset'] = (int) $this->uri->segment(4);
  $this->load->view('sitemanager/workshop/viewallworkshoppay',$data);
```

and i use `<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>`  code in my view page to show pagination links.But the  pagination links are not showing in browser.When i print  `$data['query']` the records are limited according to  `$per_page` variabe.

Comment: If you have data record less than `per_page`, the `create_links` will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Create the links in your controller first. You also have to make sure you're grabbing enough records to make links. I usually set my per page to 1 when first setting it up to make sure it's working.

Controller:

```
  $data['success'] = "";
  $data['error'] = "";
  $data['offset'] = 0;

  $this->load->library('pagination');
  $per_page = 4;
  $total = $this->m_workshop->totalworkshoppay();
  $baseUrl = site_url('sitemanager/workshop/workshopayment');
  $data['query'] = $this->m_workshop->getallwpay($per_page, (int) $this->uri->segment(4));     
  $confignew['base_url'] = $baseUrl;
  $confignew['total_rows'] = $total;
  $confignew['per_page'] = $per_page;
  $confignew['uri_segment'] = '4';
  $this->pagination->initialize($confignew);
  $data['pages'] = $this->pagination->create_links();


  $data['offset'] = (int) $this->uri->segment(4);
  $this->load->view('sitemanager/workshop/viewallworkshoppay',$data);
```

View:

```
echo $pages;
```

Comment: thanks,  i found the problem value of  $total variable is 0 there is a problem in the return value